# Mysqli SELECT ? (bind_param)

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to query the data in a column dependent on the variable $garment. The query works until I try to bind the parameter $garment . Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
//THIS WORKS
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT $garment FROM user WHERE uid=?")) {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $uid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

//DOESN'T WORK - $total returns the value of $garment
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT ? FROM user WHERE uid=?")) {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $garment, $uid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because with prepared statements you only can build **values** (not identifiers). That's it

```
SELECT ?
```

becomes

```
SELECT 'somevalue'
```

The first code is the correct one but to be safe you must ensure that the `$garment` variable value is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use markers for the column name. So you'll have to specify the actual column name w/o a marker.

From the [official php docs](http://php.net//manual/en/function.maxdb-stmt-prepare.php)

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column
>   names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a
>   SELECT statement), or to specify both operands of a binary operator
>   such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because
>   it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. In general,
>   parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Languange (DML)
>   statements, and not in Data Defination Language (DDL) statements.